# PHP Object Parse

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using something returns this object

```
object(Kubernetes\Model\Io\K8s\Api\Apps\V1\DeploymentList)#47 (6) {
  ["apiVersion"]=>
  string(7) "apps/v1"
  ["items"]=>
  NULL
  ["kind"]=>
  string(14) "DeploymentList"
  ["metadata"]=>
  NULL
  ["isRawObject":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["rawData":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["kind"]=>
    string(14) "DeploymentList"
    ["apiVersion"]=>
    string(7) "apps/v1"
    ["metadata"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["selfLink"]=>
      string(25) "/apis/apps/v1/deployments"
      ["resourceVersion"]=>
      string(7) "2712707"
    }
    ["items"]=>
    array(61) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["metadata"]=>
        array(9) {
          ["name"]=>
```

as the code above i need to reach to name under metadata under items element i can't do foreach loop because of this ""rawData":protected"

I need to reach to this path RawData >> Items >> metadata >> Name

Comment: Where does the class come from? Are there any methods for accessing that data? Also, this question doesn't have anything to do with composer, so you should remove that tag.

Comment: what is this *something* you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can have multiple `items` values, you probably want a foreach over those values. Try something like this:

```
$data = // your object
foreach ($data->rawData['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['metadata']['name'];
}
```